# How to print the difference between two dates from two files using awk

Tags: awk

I need to print the difference (in days) between the oldest day of file 1 ($2) and date of file 2 ($2) for each unique id ($1). so that I can have the Id ($1) and days difference as an output file.

File 1

```
102 2008-06-12 11:08:12 23
105 2005-05-16 20:15:05 15
102 2009-01-30 13:16:45 38
105 2006-06-14 15:30:25 45
102 2009-04-13 24:25:30 45
105 2006-07-23 13:23:30 12
108 2004-05-21 12:25:15 15
108 2005-04-29 06:15:13 23
```

File 2

```
102 20060305 13
105 20040530 12
108 20021225 21
```

Desired output

```
102 827 
105 351
108 511
```

Comment: What have you tried this far, and where in your progress are you stuck? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have **GNU awk** with `mktime` function

```
awk '
    FNR == NR{
        d = mktime(gensub("[-:]", " ", "g", $2 FS $3))
        if(D[$1] > d || ! D[$1])
            D[$1] = d
        next
    }
    {
        d = substr($2, 1, 4) FS substr($2, 5, 2) FS substr($2, 7) " 0 0 0"
        printf "%i %i\n", $1, (D[$1] - mktime(d)) / 86400
    }
    ' file1 file2
```

will produce

```
102 830
105 351
108 513
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
#!/bin/bash
#changing to stamp
stamp1=$(date -d '2008-12-12 11:08:12' +"%s")
stamp2=$(date -d '20081210' +"%s")
#st2date1=$(date --date="@$stamp1" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#st2date2=$(date --date="@$stamp2" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#echo "$st2date1 -- $st2date2"
day='86400'
if [[ "$stamp1" -gt "$stamp2" ]]; then
  dif1=$(($stamp1-$stamp2))
  dif=$(( $dif1 / $day ))
  echo "Diffrent = $dif days"
else
  dif1=$(($stamp2-$stamp1))
  dif=$(( $dif1 / $day ))
  echo "Diffrent = $dif days"
fi
```